# Prevent users to have multiple sessions with JWT Tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I am building an application which uses JWT bearer authentication in ASP.NET Core. I need to prevent users to have multiple sessions open at the same time. I am wondering if there is way using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer middleware  to list out all the tokens of an user and then verify if there are other tokens issued for that user in order to invalidate the incoming authentication request.

If the claims are able to be validated on the server, I guess that in order to do that, the server has a record of those claims and the user who owns them. Right?

Any ideas How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Use reference tokens and when a user relogs revoke all old tokens.

Comment: reference tokens?  Could you please elaborate more your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Or one example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Mardoxx is right. For more information see https://youtu.be/BdKmZ7mPNns?t=12m54s
In other words: the feature you want to implement is not acheivable with JWT unless you add a token revocation support. If you do so then you will loose the main benefit of the JWT (stateless) hence reference tokens should be used.

Comment: Or  implement revocation storing the date of the last issue token for each user, and do not accept previous tokens. You still lose JWT stateless, but the implementation is lightweight

Comment: Thanks guys. Wel,l I have achieved my goal, saving in the db the timestamp when the user login, adding that timestamp in the payload of the token and then adding an additional layer of security to validate the JWT against the db, returning 401 if the timestamp doesn't match.

Comment: Depending on what sts you are using that may already be included in the token as the iat claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved my goal, saving in the db the timestamp when the user login, adding that timestamp in the payload of the token and then adding an additional layer of security to validate the JWT against the db, returning 401 if the timestamp doesn't match. This is the code implemented with .net Core 2.0 if someone need it.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            .......

            if (userSecurityKey != null)
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                       // This claim allows us to store information and use it without accessing the db
                        new Claim("userSecurityKey", userDeserialized.SecurityKey.ToString()),
                        new Claim("timeStamp",timeStamp),
                        new Claim("verificationKey",userDeserialized.VerificationKey.ToString()),
                        new Claim("userName",userDeserialized.UserName)

                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

               // Updates timestamp for the user if there is one
                VerificationPortalTimeStamps userTimeStamp = await _context.VerificationPortalTimeStamps.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.UserName == userDeserialized.UserName);

                if (userTimeStamp != null)
                {
                    userTimeStamp.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
                    _context.Entry(userTimeStamp).State = EntityState.Modified;
                   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    _context.VerificationPortalTimeStamps.Add(new VerificationPortalTimeStamps { TimeStamp = timeStamp, UserName = userDeserialized.UserName });
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }


                // return basic user info (without password) and token to store client side                   
                return Json(new
                {
                    userName = userDeserialized.UserName,
                    userSecurityKey = userDeserialized.SecurityKey,
                    token = tokenString
                });
            }

            return Unauthorized();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Then, to configure the JWT Bearer Authentication with .Net Core 2.0

Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        .................     

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();

        ...........

    }
```

To configure the JWT Bearer authentication:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        ............


        var key = Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"];

        byte[] keyAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyAsBytes),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true

                };

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (Configuration["AppSettings:IsGodMode"] != "true")
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;


                        return Task.FromResult<object>(0);
                    }
                };
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                o.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenHandler());
            });

        services.AddMvc()                
            .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });


        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


        return provider;
    }
```

Then, we implement the custom validation in the controller as follows:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getcandidate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCandidateAsync()
    {

        try
        {
            .....

            //Get user from the claim
            string userName = User.FindFirst("UserName").Value;

            //Get timestamp from the db for the user
            var currentUserTimeStamp = _context.VerificationPortalTimeStamps.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == userName).TimeStamp;

           // Compare timestamp from the claim against timestamp from the db
            if (User.FindFirst("timeStamp").Value != currentUserTimeStamp)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ...........

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```