# Control over user logins using Identity core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity

As I know Identity core with individual authentication mode uses JWT standard for authentication. Hense JWT is stateless, it does not keep any data about user logins. Now I want if a user logs in second time, invalidate the previously generated token. So that I have read about this for example in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114492/prevent-users-to-have-multiple-sessions-with-jwt-tokens) and tryed to save the time I generate the token and also store that time into the token itself as a custom claim. And I have reached the following:

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] User_Login model)
        {
                ...
                await this.updateLastLogin(user.Id, now);
                ...
        }

        private async Task updateLastLogin(string UserId, DateTime now)
        {
            localDbContext.TokenTimeStamps.RemoveRange(localDbContext.TokenTimeStamps.Where(tts => tts.UserId == UserId));
            localDbContext.TokenTimeStamps.Add(new TokenTimeStamp(){
                TimeStamp = now.ToString("yyyyddMMHHmmssfff"),
                UserId = UserId,
            });
            localDbContext.SaveChanges();
            dbContext.Users.First(usr => usr.Id == UserId)
                .LastLoginDateTime = now;
            dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

using these lines of code now I have saved the timestamp to check it later in the authentication step. Now I am trying to do the job in a middleware. So that I have written the following in Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
                var localDbContext = services.GetService<CollegeLocalDbContext>();

                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    var authorizationHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorizationHeader))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(authorizationHeader);
                        var UserId = context.User.Identity.Name;
                        var LastLoginDateTime = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(clm => clm.Type == "LastLoginDateTime");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{UserId} - {LastLoginDateTime?.Value}");
                        if (
                            true
                            // || LastLoginDateTime == null || !localDbContext.TokenTimeStamps.Any(tts => tts.TimeStamp == LastLoginDateTime.Value && tts.UserId == UserId)
                        )
                        {
                            context.User = null;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
                    await next();
                });
            }
            app.UseAuthorization();
            ...
        }
```

now I have a major and a minor problem to solve:

**Major:** How should I break the authentication job? I have tested to emptize `context.User` but it won't work currectly.

**Minor:** In the condition of the short-circuited if (`if (true || ...)`)  when using `localDbContext`, it says that this object is disposed. So where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the Minor problem. The `Configure` method is not called for each request. The line: `var localDbContext = services.GetService<CollegeLocalDbContext>();` will be executed only first time. At the second request only the anonymous method `async (context, next)` will be triggered and of course now you will not have any `localDbContext` set.

Comment: Note that `localDbContext` is not null but is disposed. For this problem, I think the lifecycle of the startup disposes the context while its object is still accessible.